# Xamarin HttpClient request on Local network gets NameResolutionFailure error

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

Need to make a request with a local network server. If machine name is known, but not IP address.

```
string serverAddress = "mylocalserver";
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var url = $"http://{serverAddress}/";
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

but it fails with

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure

Comment: Is your server situated in a domain? if so, your address normally is something like: `mylocalserver.yourdomain.local`. Anyhow, the error indicates that the name resolving failes, which is usually due to a (local)DNS error.

Comment: @Stefan The thing is I can do it with browser, http://mylocalserver/ works, but when i request it with device it doesn't

Comment: is the browser on the device?

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, you are right, it was all about address and `mylocalserver.yourdomain.local` works ok

Comment: I'll post it as answer. Maybe it can help someone else sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NameResolutionFailure` is typically a DNS name resolve error.

In general, if your server is in a domain (and configured correctly), you should be ale to reach it by it's full name:

> yourlocalserver.yourdomain.local

If you don't have a domain, than you can also configure a "DNS override" in the local system. This is different per OS. For example, in windows its the `host` file located in `%WINPATH%\System32\drivers\etc`.

Third, you can have a DNS in your network without a fully configured domain. If the server is in it you should consult the DNS for the correct address.